# Length of list in dictionary (with defaultdict to create dictionary) python

Tags: python, dictionary

This is how I generated my dictionary from the lists shown below:

```
Genes = ['A2M', 'A2M', 'ACADS', 'ACADVL']

Isoforms = ['NM_000014', 'NM_000016', 'NM_000017', 'NM_000018']

ExonPos = ['9220303,9220778,9221335,9222340,9223083,9224954,9225248,9227155,9229351,9229941,9230296,9231839,9232234,9232689,9241795,9242497,9242951,9243796,9246060,9247568,9248134,9251202,9251976,9253739,9254042,9256834,9258831,9259086,9260119,9261916,9262462,9262909,9264754,9264972,9265955,9268359,', '76190031,76194085,76198328,76198537,76199212,76200475,76205664,76211490,76215103,76216135,76226806,76228376,', '121163570,121164828,121174788,121175158,121175639,121176082,121176335,121176622,121176942,121177098,', '7123149,7123440,7123782,7123922,7124084,7124242,7124856,7125270,7125495,7125985,7126451,7126962,7127131,7127286,7127464,7127639,7127798,7127960,7128127,7128275,']
#Length = len(ExonPos)

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

for k, iso, exon in zip(Genes, Isoforms, ExonPos):
    d[k][iso] = exon.split(",")
    length = len(d[exon])
    print length    
print(d)
```

This allowed me to make my dictionary with repeated keys. However, now I'm trying to find the length of the individual lists in my dictionary as shown with `length = len(d[exon])`, however, my output keeps giving me zeros. Is there something special about using `defaultdict` that I'm not aware of? Maybe it's my version of python (which is 2.7.6)? I've tried multiple different ways, but I feel like the `len()` function should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access by the  keys:

```
length = len(d[k][iso])
```

`exon.split(",")` is the value. `d[k][iso]` are the two keys to access the value.

With a normal dict you would get a `keyError` but because you are using a defaultdict you are actually temporarily creating a key value pairing where the value is an  empty list.

Answer (score 5):

Its because of that you are printing the length of `d[exon]` and your defaultdict has not any key with name `exon` instead you need :

```
len(d[k][iso])
```

Then the result will be :

```
37
13
11
21
```

Comment: You're right. Darn, I thought I tried that. Thank you!